# Find posterior distribution of Poisson process knowing that the prior is Exponential$(1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

This is the problem:
Bus arrival times form a Poisson process with intensity 
measured in buses per hour. Your prior distribution on  is that  is
an exponential random variable, Exponential$(1)$. Suppose that you observe  buses in
 hours. Find the density function of the posterior distribution for . Identify this
distribution.

What I thought is to write:
$$f_{ \lambda | X}\left( \lambda | x\right) \propto f_{\lambda }\left( \lambda \right) \cdot f_{ X| \lambda }\left( x| \lambda \right)$$
where $f_{\lambda }\left( \lambda \right) = e^{-\lambda}$ . I have a problem calculating  $f_{ X| \lambda }\left( x| \lambda \right)$, since I don't know how to use the fact $k$ buses are seen in $n$ hours. I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed or a possible solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation $X$ is the random variable denoting the number of buses observed in $n$ hours. Since the arrivals follow a Poisson process, $(X \mid \lambda) \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(n \lambda)$. Now following your idea to use Bayes' rule, what can you say about $f_{X \mid \lambda}(x \mid \lambda)$?

Comment: Would this be just $e^{-\lambda n}\cdot \dfrac{\left( \lambda n\right) ^{n}}{k!}$?

Comment: That's right. If you plug that in, you get the form of your posterior density (up to the normalisation constant).

Comment: Thank you! To find the normalizing constant is it just sufficient to integrate the expression from 0 to infinity?

Comment: That's right. Sometimes, I believe, that you can also spot the resulting distribution "by inspection", especially when you are working with a "nice prior" (e.g. a conjugate prior).